# Create a python script that can make multiple Classes

Tags: python, class

so my problem is that I have a list of txt file that contain the coordinate points of all the states in the US. Right now my idea is to create class for each states in the US with the coordinate as attributes. Is there any fast way to do so? For example

```
class nevada:
    def __init__(self):
      self.coordinate = [list of long lat tuple that get from txt file]
```

The goal is to create like another 51 class like this.
Thank you so much in advance.

EDIT: Just to be clear, I try to make this into a pip package so that I can use later. Like if I type US.nevada, it will return the coordinate of that state

Comment: If the states don't have different behavior but only different data you shouldn't create own classes for them, only own objects of a common class. If you really want classes you can use "exec" function in combination with some string formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about I make a class US but the attribute is the coordinate of each state. Like US.indiana will return a list of coordinates. I want to package this into a pip package in order to use it later

Comment: I would do this only if you are sure that no more additional information should be stored like area or population. But if so, the US object should return an object of State type which provides all these informations e. g. as attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for:

```
state_names = ('Alaska', 'California')
coordinates = [[10, 10], [20, 20]]

class State :
    def __init__ (self, coordinates) :
        self.coordinates = coordinates
index = 0
for state in state_names :
    globals () [state] = State (coordinates [index]) 
    index += 1

print (Alaska.coordinates)
print (California.coordinates)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I want is like create class that store in the information of the state border and then push it to pip package for uses in the future.

Comment: But it's pure data, it would be more convinient to receive this data via a webapi